# ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined in emailjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email

I'm trying to use emailjs to send email to user after submission of form but I'm getting this error:

```
FAILED... ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\api\sendPost.js:8:21     
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.sendPost (C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\api\sendPost.js:7:12)
    at Object.send (C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\methods\send\send.js:25:23)
    at C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\routes\index.js:197:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Awesome\Websites\Client Websites\alumates-landing-page\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

According to the error, the XMLHttpRequest is not defined in emailjs's sendpost.js

I did not modify this file. I just installed emailjs the regular way using

```
npm install emailjs-com --save
```

Please, anybody know how to fix? This is my route:

```
router.post('/groups/join', function (req, res) {

//handle form submission here

var templateParams = {
    url: url,
    group_name: group_name, //gotten from form submission value
    user_name: joinRequest.user_name, //gotten from form submission value
    email: joinRequest.email //gotten from form submission value
  }

  emailjs.send(serviceID, groupID, templateParams)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
      res.redirect("/login")
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('FAILED...', error);
    });

})
```

I have also required emailjs and xhr at the top of my route:

```
var xhr = require("xhr");
var emailjs = require("emailjs-com");
emailjs.init("user_CPxhncQgw2s5e4nNwbu36")
```

Comment: having the same issue. any updates?

Comment: Just use a lib meant for Node, not browsers, and you should be fine.

Comment: No I wasn't able to sort the issue out. I had to find another alternative. I use Nodemailer now, instead of emailjs

Answer (score 3):

You have to move the `emailjs.send` method to front-end. I even installed xhr2 and replaced the code in the module. I got a log saying `emailjs` does not work on non-browser applications.

Comment: This is correct. After following Vipul Chaudhary's answer, the issue of XMLHttpRequest not being defined goes away. However, you're presented with a new error that "API calls are disabled for non-browser applications".

All emailjs calls must be done from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

None of  this makes any sense. Email.js targets browsers and their APIs. Importing xhr at the top makes no difference; it does not make XHR APIs available in the global scope of Node.

If you REALLY wanted to use it you would need to stub the XHR implementation by using the `xhr` package to create the skeleton, but it is *really* the wrong way to go. Just find an email lib targeting Node to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

For using XHR in node js you need to use an external library like xhr2
First, install it

```
 npm install xhr2
```

Now, require it

```
 var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: The error is coming from the package I installed, not from my own code. According to the reference error, the error is coming from "node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\api\sendPost.js:8:21"

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the package and I still get the error.

I've also installed and uninstalled xhr2 multiple times. The error still persists.

Answer (score -1):

Gotcha I have a solution,

Tight Your sit, You are going to modify one file into the node_modules folder.

first you need to install xhr2

```
 npm install xhr2
```

1. go to node_modules/emailjs-com/cjs/api
2. open sendPost.js file
3. it may look like something this

[image]

4. Now add this two line at some appropriate space, on the top of sendPost.js file

```js
 var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

That's it.